# Error Class not found before deleting generated folder

Tags: magento-2.2.5, di, code-generation, preference

I have created a preference to override a class but constantly getting error "Class not found" before deleting "generated" folder content:

Error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Vendor\Module\Plugin\Firebear\Loader' not found in /var/www/html/Dr/Project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:111 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/Dr/Project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject
```

Created Preference:

```
<preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\ReadHandler" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\FireBear\ReadHandler" />
```

Preference Class:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\FireBear;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Plugin\FireBear\Loader;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Framework\EntityManager\Operation\ExtensionInterface;
{
class ReadHandler implements ExtensionInterface
/**
 * @var Loader
 */
private $optionLoader;

/**
 * ReadHandler constructor
 *
 * @param Loader $optionLoader
 */
public function __construct(Loader $optionLoader)
{
    $this->optionLoader = $optionLoader;
}
```

**After running :**

```
bin/magento s:up 
bin/magento s:d:c 
bin/magento c:f
```

This error is coming but after deleting `generated/*` this error seems resolved.

Then again this error comes after every `bin/magento s:up` && `bin/magento s:d:c` && `bin/magento c:f`

Comment: Vendor\Module\Plugin\FireBear\Loader file exist or not ?

Comment: Yes it exists in my custom module. Right after I delete generated folder content this error is not coming

Comment: Seems as if I have a typo Firebear insteed of FireBear. :(  Let me check

Comment: Yes it was a typo thanks a lot @RonakRathod anyways